# Coding puzzle which is going tough

Tags: cipher

Can you solve this coding puzzle?

If:

> **RAIL = KCTN**

and

> **SPEAK = CGRUM**

then

**AVOID = ?**

Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Then:

> **AVOID = KQXCF**

We use the following cipher:

> ROT2 (Caesar cipher with shift 2)
>
> ```
> Plaintext:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> Ciphertext: CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
> ```

But there's a twist! We:

> Start from the second-last letter in the word, go backwards from there and finally add the last letter of the word, then cipher.

I.e.:

> ```
> RAIL  -> IARL  -> KCTN
> SPEAK -> AEPSK -> CGRUM
> AVOID -> IOVAD -> KQXCF
> ```

Comment: It's almost like reverse igpay atinlay.

Comment: I feel like somewhere a teacher is gonna read this word for word, not here though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> KQXCF

Because

> All the letters of the word are written in reverse order except the last letter of word and in the group of letters so obtained. Then, each letter is moved 2 steps forward to get the code.
>
>  **RAIL = IARL = KCTN**
>
>  **SPEAK = AEPSK = CGRUM**
>
>  **AVOID = IOVAD = KQXCF**

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is almost identical to [my answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/55228/30903)

Comment: @boboquack . Yes, he has literally copied your answer. I think that he was trying to make your answer in such a way that everyone could understand it. But I will still say it is a copy of your answer